# URLs with domain name in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, url, routes

I'm pretty new to working with Symfony and I cannot find a way around my problem:

I have a domain, say `testing.domain.tld` where I deploy my app for testing purposes. Routing works as expected for all my self written controllers, but when i send an email or in easyadmin, the generated URL is something like `127.0.0.1:8080/route` instead of `testing.domain.tld/route`.

This can probably be done in config, but I do not see where/how...

I would be very thankful for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure the router request context base url. If you are using at least Symfony 5.1 you can configure it via the `framework.router.default_uri` configuration key, otherwise you have to specify the host, scheme and base path of your application.

[Read more about this feature in this post from symfony blog](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-simpler-request-context)

Comment: thank you for that link! i haven't seen this before and i think this will be the solution, even though it didn't work in my first try

Comment: I just realized, that my reverse proxy was set-up incorrectly (missing preserve host) and the only thing missing was the correct http-context for my controller!